# ASSERTION ERROR The provided value must be an instance of a DOM Node but got AppHostView(1)

Tags: angular, nativescript

a hava a an app than worked fine several weeks aggo, but I have just retruned to work with it an when I debug it, it keep sending me the error:

ASSERTION ERROR The provided value must be an instance of a DOM Node but got AppHostView(1)

Please I need some advise.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your components (nativescript, angular, webpack, ...) versions ran out of sync. A reset of the webpack config and the project might help to restore a working version.

try this:

1. ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs
2. rm -rf node_modules
3. rm -rf platforms
4. rm -rf hooks
5. rm package-lock.json
6. npm i
7. tns build android or ios

If you are on Nativescript 7 there is the `ns clean` command that does this for you.

Comment: Hi, you should explain why the OP should try what you are suggesting. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on answering questions.

Comment: Did Jose's suggestion work? I am facing the exact same error on an application that used to work a couple of months ago, but today, when I tried to start it again it gives me the same error. If that did not work, did you find another solution?

Comment: If it worked for me, try this more:
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf platforms
rm -rf hooks
rm package-lock.json
npm i
tns build android or ios

Answer (score 0):

for me it was app.component.html which was causing the error.
It Was

```
<StackLayout>
    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
```

changed to

```
<Label text="demo text"></Label>
```

error gone. trying to figure out how to use page-router-outlet now

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, and I cannot explain the mechanics behind the workaround, was deleting the "hooks", "node-modules" and "platforms" folders as well as the "package-lock.json" and "webpack.config.js" files and issuing a new "npm install" command.